# giving me error on printing, not printing the lastname, firstname's initial(PYTHON3)

Tags: list, python-3.x, operator-keyword

Write function `lastF()` that take as input two strings of the form `'FirstName'` and `'Lastname'`, respectively, and returns a string of the form `'LastName, F. '` (only the initial should be output for the firstname).

Whenever I print `line1`, it just comes back to the code that I put instead of the lastname and first initial.

Suppose to look like this:

```
'Camus, A.'
```

This is what I got so far:

```
firstname= input ('Enter yout firstname: ')
lastname= input ('Enter your lastname: ')
line1 = ('lastname + " , " + firstname[0]')
print(line1)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you've made your code into a string by putting single quotes on either end. Remove the single quotes and the parentheses when assigning to line1, and it'll do what you want it to do, providing firstname has at least one character in it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix:

```
firstname= input ('Enter yout firstname: ')
lastname= input ('Enter your lastname: ')

output = lastname.capitalize() + " , " + (firstname.capitalize())[0] + '.'
print(output)
```

And, MHardwick is right.